# "None of [Float64Index([nan, nan], dtype='float64')] are in the [index]" setting col A value if col B contains string

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, text-mining

I have a dataframe (called `corpus`) with one column (`tweet`) and 2 rows:

```
['check, tihs, out, this, bear, love, jumping, on, this, plant']
['i, can, t, bear, the, noise, from, that, power, plant, it, make, me, jump']
```

I have a list (called `vocab`) of unique words in the column:

```
['check',
 'tihs',
 'out',
 'this',
 'bear',
 'love',
 'jumping',
 'on',
 'plant',
 'i',
 'can',
 't',
 'the',
 'noise',
 'from',
 'that',
 'power',
 'it',
 'make',
 'me',
 'jump']
```

I want to add a new column for each word in vocab. I want all values for the new columns to be zero, except for when the `tweet` contains the word, in which case I want the value of the word column to be 1.

So I tried running the code below:

```
for word in vocab:
    corpus[word] = 0
    corpus.loc[corpus["tweet"].str.contains(word), word] = 1
```

...and the following error was displayed:

```
"None of [Float64Index([nan, nan], dtype='float64')] are in the [index]"
```

How can I check to see if the tweet contains the word, and then if so, set the value of the new column for the word to 1?

Comment: I suggest you use `sklearn`'s `CountVectorizer`, it'll save you lots of time

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at the documentation.

Comment: I've had a look at `sklearn`'s `CountVectorizer` and can't see how I can do lemmatization before the bag of words is created. Do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `corpus['tweet']` is list type, each is a skeleton. So `.str.contains` would returns `NaN`. You may want to do:

```
# turn tweets into strings
corpus["tweet"] = [x[0] for x in corpus['tweet']]

# one-hot-encode
for word in vocab:
    corpus[word] = 0
    corpus.loc[corpus["tweet"].str.contains(word), word] = 1
```

But then this may not be what you want, because `contains` will search for all substrings, e.g. `this girl goes to school` will returns `1` in both columns `is` and `this`.

Based on your data, you can do:

```
corpus["tweet"] = [x[0] for x in corpus['tweet']]

corpus = corpus.join(corpus['tweet'].str.get_dummies(', ')
                         .reindex(vocab, axis=1, fill_value=0)
                    )
```

Comment: Thank you. This gets me part way there. I want it to not flag 1 for 't' for tweets that contains words that have 't' in them, only for tweets where 't' is a separate token on its own. Is there an alternative way to use .contains() or an alternative function that will let me be that specific?

Comment: The last piece of code in my answer woud do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

l = ['check, this, out, this, bear, love, jumping, on, this, plant',
'i, can, t, bear, the, noise, from, that, power, plant, it, make, me, jump']
vect = CountVectorizer()
X = pd.DataFrame(vect.fit_transform(l).toarray())
X.columns = vect.get_feature_names()
```

Output:

```
bear  can  check  from  it  jump  ...  out  plant  power  that  the  this
0     1    0      1     0   0     0  ...    1      1      0     0    0     3
1     1    1      0     1   1     1  ...    0      1      1     1    1     0
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I would be able to apply lemmatization before it creates that bag of words dataframe? I can't see anything in the sklearn documentation for CountVectorizer about stemming or lemmatization.

Comment: Last time I needed to do that I used `nltk`:  `from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer`
`wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()` , `df['text_lemmatized']=df.text.apply(lambda x: [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in x if w not in stpwords ]` . Something along those lines should work. I think there are more efficient options now, but you're problem seems to not be too big, so it shouldn't be a problem